# Animation or transition just using style attribute inside a tag

Tags: css, animation, inline-styles

It is possible?
I mean this:

```
<div style="?css animation?"> Content </div>
```

It can be any tag, or maybe triggering the animation or transition from other tag.
This question is because I will like to use animations and transitions in a web app, but this app just let me use css included in the style tag attribute.

Pseudo clases I guess are out of the question so I can not trigger transitions, neither I can use javascript, so onmouseover or similar kind of stuff are out of the question.

Animations on the other hand needs their keyframes settings, and I can not set keyframes inside a style tag.. (or can I?). I read something similar here:
https://css-tricks.com/animate-to-an-inline-style/
But I guess it would not work for what I am asking.

Not sure if there is a hack to import a css from an attribute or just achieve animations in chrome browsers (another thing, I have not access to the head section of the html).

Yeah I know, it seems mission impossible, I was just wonder in case there is some kind of trick to achieve this even if the animation is very limited.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, afaik.

Atleast not for those animations that require `:hover` or `keyframes` as you mentioned. However, it is possible by including animations attached to `<style>` contained within the same html page. Or by injecting css code using js code on the same html page . This suits if you are okay with CSS resting in the same file.

> The link you've mentioned is **NOT** using inline CSS for animation; it has a separate CSS file.

Comment: Yeah, but I can not use <style> ... </style>, that is automatic remove from the code. I know that the possibilities to achieve this are almost none, but I will let the question open just in case there is some hack that I did not think before.  After some days I will mark this as answered. Also, yeah I know that the link example did not help, but maybe the fact that you dont need to set the To or 100% may help to find another way.

Comment: Then I think its kinda hard, probably you need to find a _hack_ ! Are you doing this for an email or something?

Comment: I am doing this for a page called (mercado libre) where you can insert product descriptions using html.  buf it seems that for some security risk, they just allow css included in the tag.